# Не могу запустить gunicorn

Tags: gunicorn

Я новичок в gunicorn. Не могу его запустить, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, добавляя изменения на сервер, в файле requirements.txt забыл внести новый пакет, скачав его на сервере и перезапустив gunicron сайт стал работать.